# Deployment to instances using JBoss 7.1 as domain controller

Tags: java, deployment, jboss7.x, setup-deployment, domaincontroller

I am using JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final as a domain controller. We want to define multiple server instances which are bound to their own individual IP address and control them over one JBoss instance which is the domain controller.

We want to centralize the management of data sources and JDBC deployments using the domain controller. There should be isolated deployments of .war files to each defined server group only accessible by the specific IP addresses we bound the instance to.

**Setup**

The setup is basically like this:

```
DC (Domain Controller)
    |
     - development (development, development-server-group)
           |
            - deployment1.war
    |
     - staging (staging, staging-server-group)
           |
            - deployment2.war
```

The *Domain Controller (DC)* shares the data source, JDBC driver deployment and logging configuration with the instances.

**What works**

We do have a working domain controller which can start and manage the instances.

**The problem**

Is there a way to do an individual deployment to an isolated server group?

I understand that a server group is a virtual, cluster-independent grouping of multiple JBoss instances, so I created multiple server groups to model my requirements (each server group gets an individual data source and deployment).

I tried to deploy a .war file to a specific server group via the JBoss CLI, but JBoss always tells me that this server group is not known. Theses images show my problem:

[image: The deployment shows up in the general deployment content tab.]
[image: The deployment does not show up in development-server-group.]

The command I used:

```
deploy --server-group=development-server-group api.war
```

Another approach I tried was to deploy the .war file using the Maven JBoss plugin, but this results in a deployment on the domain controller which is therefore accessible to all server groups.

Is there any way to implement this requirement??

Comment: I figured out that the command "deploy --server-group=development-server-group --name=api.war development.war" will deploy the file "development.war" with the runtime name "api.war". This is the expected behavior. I am now investigating if there is an issue with the JBoss Maven plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did two things:

1. I am using `jboss-web.xml` to specify a context root, which is the same for all deployments (which is OK, because we have one deployment for each server group).
2. I started a feature request for the runtime-name parameter which is missing the JBoss 7 Maven plugin: https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin/issues/52